# MVC Identity 2 - Account Confirmation email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using identity 2 for registration and login in a new MVC solution, i have coded the register to send a confirmation email when someone registers but then i'm still able to log in without verifying (clicking the verify link in email).

I have used the standard code that is provided when Indentity 2 is installed via Nuget. 
i have also used this example http://www.typecastexception.com/post/2014/04/20/ASPNET-Identity-20-Setting-Up-Account-Validation-and-Two-Factor-Authorization.aspx#Account-Validation:-How-it-works and i get the same.

Am i misunderstanding this? i thought that i wouldn't be able to login until verified as per every other site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing about the login process itself that enforces that the email be confirmed. It seems that the sample projects don't care for login purposes, but they do check before allowing a password reset. As a result, you can adapt the code from that to add to your login action if you so desire. Essentially, you'd just do something like:

```
if (!(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "E-mail address has not been confirmed");
}

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, that was exactly what i needed. I did add this line above :
   var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email); 
as i only have the email at this point. I have edited your post to add this line in to help others. thanks